# Ionic changes not being reflected in iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm successfully able to convert the angular app into an ionic4 application using Ionic and Capacitor.  However, when I make changes to the src folder, it doesn't update in the iOS app when I run it.

I'm doing the following:

```
npx cap add ios (only first time)
ionic build --prod
npx cap copy
npx cap open ios
```

More so, I'm noticing the `/www` folder not being updated with my changes. Instead, there is a `/dist` folder being updated... strange. This makes sense, because `npx cap copy` copies the `/www` folder into the `ios/App/public` folder.

How do I get my changes in `/src` into my ionic ios build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I do when I make a change to my codebase and want to see the change in my Capacitor app:

I have a command in my package.json which allows me to run 'npm run build-cap' instead of running each of these commands one at time.

"build-cap": "eliminate ios && ionic build && npx cap add ios && npx cap update ios && npx cap open ios",

For me it was necessary to wipe out the ios folder and rebuild the www directory by running 'ionic build' to see my changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to see changes as you update your codebase, instead of the commands above (which are for release builds), you should type `ionic capacitor run ios --livereload --external` and make sure your phone and PC are on the same Wifi network. This will build your application in debug mode, and open XCode, from which you will have to start the application. Further changes to your codebase are instantly reflected in the app.